# compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=

Tags: java

Recently I updated my java version to 11 and I'm getting this error while building the application.
Any thought on this ?

he NullPointerException is thrown from `com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1235)`

This is the stacktrace:

```
    compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.6, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1235)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitReturn(Flow.java:1210)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCReturn.accept(JCTree.java:1546)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitBlock(Flow.java:997)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1020)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitMethodDef(Flow.java:964)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:866)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitClassDef(Flow.java:927)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:774)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:1327)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:1317)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow.analyzeTree(Flow.java:218)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1401)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.flow(JavaCompiler.java:1375)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:973)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:154)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:122)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-05-12T00:56:46.757446500Z 
> Task :compileJava FAILED
:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 38.574 secs.
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge.

Comment: He Tony, I think it might be helpful to add which gradle version you use, cause the error seems to originate from there.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 5.2.1 and the project complied correctly in java 8 and when I upgraded to Java 11 I'm getting this error.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8237565?focusedCommentId=14348860&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel